# Update contact detail android

Tags: android

I am working on the an application in which I want to update contact of particular person. When I update only contact first and last name then it working fine but I want to update full detail of contact like email address, number, postal addres etc.

Please provide me some useful link. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

each field (email, name, adress) has its on mime type, which you should use
in order to update the field.

lets try to update the email for instance.

First, you should find the detail you want to update.
we will work with Data table, where each Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID represents a detail
about some contact.

So, we need to find the Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID where the id is the id of the contact you want
to edit.

Now we need to find the mimetype (the specific row which represents the detail) of
email (Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE).

The data of an email is stored in the column Email.DATA - there we put the new email.

if you want a specific email type, you should add it to the query:
for example, if you want to add a home-email, then you should add Email.TYPE_HOME
to the query.

then we build a query and finally apply the change.

Here's an examle:

```
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    String emailParams = Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
    String[] emailParamsWhere = new String[] { "contact_id", Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI).withSelection(emailParams, emailParamsWhere).withValue(Email.DATA, "new email").withValue(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_HOME) 
            .build());

    try
    {
        ContentProviderResult[] res = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);

        if (res != null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    catch (RemoteException e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch (OperationApplicationException e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For updating mobile phone, use this query:

```
        String phoneParams = Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " + Phone.TYPE + " = " + Phone.TYPE_MOBILE;
        String[] phoneParamsWhere = new String[] { "contact_id", Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI).withSelection(phoneParams, phoneParamsWhere).withValue(Phone.NUMBER, "mobile_number")
                .withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_MOBILE).build());
```

Hope I helped

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code but When I used this with contact first and last name update than email type changed with unknown type. I want to update whole contact detail same as android contact api works.

Comment: simply add withValue(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_HOME) (or any type you like) to the end of the query, like in the mobile number example I posted. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, its working. can you tell me one thing ? suppose user did not insert email address but at the update time he want to insert or update email addres then how it handle ? plz help...

Comment: not sure I understand you. what do you mean by "at the update time"?

Comment: Suppose user did not insert email address at the time of new add contact but he want to insert email address at the time of update than how to handel this.

Comment: I hope i got you right. you say that a new contact has been created, but without email, and now you want to add an email to that contcat. In this case use the same query as above, but just change newUpdate to newInsert, since such row isn't exist yet.

Comment: Thank to you for giving time.